# A property is in an object but it is shown as undefined

Tags: javascript, object

Why is my `_data` undefined when it is literally right there?

[image]

Comment: It was undefined when `console.log` ran, and got a value between then and when you clicked the triangle to expand it.

Comment: The `[i]` icon at the end of the line indicates that the object changed.